# avoiding duplicate data while inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, jsp, stored-procedures

I want to avoid inserting duplicate value in my table which has auto increment id (Viewer_ID). I'm work on jsp page and I wrote prepared statement . How can I do this?? Is it better to create index in my table or write store procedure  or solve this problem with specific query in jsp page ??? If I want to write store procedure , How can I use it in my jsp page ??? Thanks

```
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement( Insert into Viewer (F_Name, L_Name, Competition_ID, City ,Phone, E-mail, Reserve_ID) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

EDIT :

```
if not exists (select F_Name, L_Name, City, Phone
, [E-mail] from Viewer where F_Name = " + fname + "
and L_Name = " + lname + " and City = " + city + " and Phone 
= " + phone + " and [E-mail] = " + email +  ") begin Insert 
into Viewer (F_Name, L_Name, Competition_ID, City ,Phone, [E-mail], Reserve_ID) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) end
```

Please tell me why this query doesn't work ???

This error occurs : Invalid column name '????'

Comment: which column should not be duplicate? just define it as `unique` at table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=avoid+duplicate+database

Comment: @Riad All of them except Competition_ID and Reserve_ID which is foreign key in other table and auto increment too!

Comment: then make a composite key ...using `alter table add unique .....`

Comment: can you give more details about writing query?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont try
something like

```
SET @SQL='if not exists (select F_Name, L_Name, City, Phone, [E-mail] 
                from Viewer 
             where F_Name = ' + @fname + '            '
                      and L_Name = ' + @lname + ' 
                  and City = ' + @city + '
                  and Phone = ' + @phone + '
                  and [E-mail] = ' + @email + ' )   ''
EXCUTE @SQL
                  begin 
                  Insert into Viewer (F_Name, 
                                      L_Name, 
                                  Competition_ID, 
                                  City ,Phone, 
                                  [E-mail], 
                                  Reserve_ID) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) end
```

Comment: Sorry , but I can't use it . because quotation marks are unreadable and get me confused!! and one more problem is , can I use this in preparedStatement ???

Comment: insert the variables (@fname,@lname,?,@city,@phone, @email,?)   and complete ? with new values.